# Trustpilot review api for different urls

Tags: php

I need to implement Trust pilot reviews on my site.
 I have integrated using script provided by Trust pilot. 
But its working for common to site.
 I want to identify for products details page. How can i integrate the Trust pilot reviews for dynamic page.

Can anyone please help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

TrustPilot gives you a unique business unit id for each URL you have registered with them. You need to make separate calls to the server using the unique business unit id and the API key they provided to use it on different websites.